# reload list contents on click of a button

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

i am trying to develop this app in android that has 3-4 buttons and a list being displayed below them. each button when clicked must reload the list with new contents based on which button was clicked.
each row in the list has a picture and two lines of text.
could some one please suggest me how do I perform the reloading part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the new adapter, with updated elements, with the listView, it will work as reloading the list view......

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the list, in whatever layout it is in (ex LinearLayout) by doing a:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)getViewById(R.id.thislayout)
```

Remove the elements from the list as you desire using:

```
ll.removeView(view);
```

edit the view object as you want (changing the source etc) then re-add it to the LinearLayout using:

```
ll.addView(view);
```